# Is this behavior due to unpredictable timings of garbage collection when it cleans up?

Tags: c#, wpf

When I change selection in a list, the dialog gets updated, reading from the file associated with that item in the list. I fixed the problem by using the `using` statement in below code.

```
    private void ViewModel_SelectedNoteChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            contentRichTextBox.Document.Blocks.Clear();

            if (VM.SelectedNote != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(VM.SelectedNote.FileLocation))
                {
                    using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(VM.SelectedNote.FileLocation, FileMode.Open))
                    {

                        var contents = new TextRange(contentRichTextBox.Document.ContentStart, contentRichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
                        contents.Load(fileStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

If I don't use the `using` statement above, its hit or miss. Sometimes it reads the contents from a file and display them, otherwise it throws an exception.

> System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file
> 'D:\EClone\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\3.rtf'
> because it is being used by another process.'

My question is why the unpredictable behavior without the `using` statement? Is it because of known unpredictability of garbage collection (when it decides to clean up), because we can never be sure when does the garbage collection cleans up the file? Is this a good example of non-deterministic nature of garbage collection? Or is it something else?

Comment: when you use, "using" statement, it calls Dispose method which closes the filestream, I don't know if it closes the filestream on the finalizer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly due to incorrect usage of `IDisposable` and GC.
Without `using`

- you open file (and thus lock it) and store a reference in a variable
- the function exits, but the file is still opened and locked.
- if GC runned before you will try to open file again - all works fine, because in a file wrapper's finalizer there is a code to close (and unlock) a file.
- if you try to access the same file before GC run - you will get exception.

In case with using, you will close and unlock file explicitly by calling `Dispose` (`using` will call it for you). `Dispose` will close and unlock file immediately without waiting GC, so with `using` your code will always work as expected.

Moreover, as you can't control, when the GC will run, the code without `using` is unstable `by design`, so even if it works fine today, it may stop working tomorrow because of the system have more free memory (and GC runs no so often as today),  or because .net update (with some GC changes/improvements) and so on.

So, as conclusion: if you have something, which implements `IDisposable`, always call `Dispose` when you not need the object anymore (with `using` or manually). You can omit calling `Dispose` only if it is explicitly allowed in documentation or guides (for example, as for `Task` class)